# Overflow hidden is not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

I need to display image as round shaped in my site so i used overflow:hidden in my css code it works fine in other browsers but not in IE11.[image: This is the output i got in iIE11]

above image is the output i got in ie
and my css code is

```
img-block {
/* position: relative; */
/* background-color: #f4f4f4; */
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: table;
font-size: 20px;
```

and my HTML code is

```
<div class="img-block">
        <div class="img">
                                <img src="https://samugam.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/profiles/44/1521531048.jpg" alt="Shamini">
                        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style

```
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You need to add `border-radius` in order to make the image a round shape.